# Building a Watch OS2 application using Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, apple-watch, watchos-2

As per Xamarin documentation Watch OS2 is supported only on simulator and still updates for device support are awaited.

https://blog.xamarin.com/watchos-2-preview-and-updates/

Is it somehow possible to build the application in Xamarin and WatchApp in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: [Xamarin.iOS 9.3 preview #3 for tvOS and WatchOS 2.0 in Visual Studio](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57111/xamarin-ios-9-3-preview-3-for-tvos-and-watchos-2-0-in-visual-studio?new=1)

> May 14 2016
>
> I'll copy a comment from another thread for cross-referencing here:
>
> > I asked the team about this. Updating the watchOS 2 preview to add bitcode support is a high priority. It is among the top priorities the engineering team will be working on after this week's Evolve conference. Apple's recent announcement that watchOS 2 will be required for all new watchOS app submissions starting in June is definitely on the minds of the engineering team.
>
> The hope is that a preview with bitcode support can be made available by the end of May, but the team is still wary of any unanticipated complications that could change that timeline.

Comment: Thanks. Just want to check is it possible to build your app using xamarin and WatchApp using Xcode? Any collaborative way to do it.

Comment: @ArunGupta Not that I know of since a watch app project can not exist on its own within Xcode and must be paired to an iOS app project. but the Xam' folks would have the final say on if there is any way to hack that

Comment: Hmmm i guessed that. So no Xamarin apps have been deployed for watch OS2 till date as they can't run on device.